# Grep in XML with Tab and carriage return

Tags: xml, grep

I would like to grep into a XML file for the folloging secuence :

```
user defined modules)
     |-->         
     <module>
```

And this is my code:

```
function check()
{
        OLDIFS=$IFS
        IFS=$'\n'

        fileArray=($(find . -type f -not -path "./folder1/*" -not -path "*/folder2/*" -not -path "./folder3/*" -name "pom.xml" \
                        | xargs awk -v RS='^$' 'match($0,/\|--> \(autogenerated code\)\t\n\t[^\n]+/,a){print a[0]}'))
        IFS=$OLDIFS

        # get length of an array
        numberOfFiles=${#fileArray[@]}

        # read all filenames
        for (( i=0; i<${numberOfFiles}; i++ ));
        do
          echo "ERROR:Found user code modules (file:line:occurrence): ${fileArray[$i]}"
        done


    if [ "$numberOfFiles" != "0" ]; then
        echo "SUMMARY:Found $numberOfFiles pom.xml file(s) containing user code modules."
        exit 1
    fi
}

check
```

Is not clear how can i deal with it, since it´s containing in the middle carriage retuns and tab, and its not as simple as retrieve the content fo one tag. Im using Shell under linux openSUSE 12.

I have tried grep -P but not compatible with multiple patterns. Some tips?

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: [edit] your question to show a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can begin thinking about how to help you.

Comment: I´ve tried to edit the code sample. The first line contains at the end of the text: TAB + ENTER.   The second line of the example start with TAB before the text. There remains the main issue. Thanks so much for your tips.

Comment: Last help please! :) I need to find exactly: (user defined modules) [ENTER]
[TAB][TAB] |--> [ENTER]        
[TAB] <module>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear but if you're trying to find

```
|--> (autogenerated code)<tab>
<tab><my code>
```

where `<tab>` represents a tab character and `<my code>` is whatever follows that 2nd tab to the end of the line, then here's one way with GNU awk:

```
awk -v RS='^$' 'match($0,/\|--> \(autogenerated code\)\t\n\t[^\n]+/,a){print a[0]}'
```

If that's not what you want then edit your question to provide a clearer description and a more truly representative example.

Comment: Thanks Ed, I´m newbie here and cannot provide all info as I would like. Your answer is very useful. After the 1st tab, there is also a carriage return, as the layout of the example. Is that solution also covering that case? Thanks once again. Tomorrow im gona test it and let your know

Comment: Yes, see the `\n` in between the 2 tabs (`\t`s) in the regexp. What do you mean `cannot provide all info as I would like`? Just copy/paste into the editor and use the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: Last help please! :) I need to find exactly: (user defined modules) [ENTER] [TAB][TAB] |--> [ENTER] [TAB] <module>

Comment: `[ENTER]` is `\n` and `[TAB]` is `\t` so that'd be `\n \t\t \|--> \n \t<module>`. If that's not what you're looking for then post a new question with a [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output. I see you've changed your question **a lot**. Change it back to what it was when I answered it so others looking for help in future find a consistent Q/A and ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks! i willl edit later as you suggest. If you can help here also will be great!: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958403/awk-grep-into-xml-file-with-non-matching-secuence