# Find XML files non containing a specific comment from shell

Tags: xml, bash, awk, grep

I want to search (awk/grep/sed) into few XML files (pom.xml file) skipping some folder. Moreover,the first condition is that they must contain the tag `<module>`.   For those cases, I want to print out those who does not contain the exactly sequence below (it's autogenerated code - It will help me to detect if somebody modified that sequence):

```
  <!--
         | Start of user code (user defined modules)
         |-->
        <!-- 
         | End of user code
         |-->
```

Im stucked here:

```
        fileArray=($(find . -type f -not -path "./folder1/*" -not -path "*/folder2/*" -not -path "./folder3/*" -name "pom.xml" \
                    | xargs awk -v RS='^$' 'match($0,/\<module>[^\n]+/,a){print a[0]}'))
```

Some tips please?

---UPDATE:

```
  #!/bin/sh

###########################################################
# Checks for "user code" <modules> defined in pom files.
###########################################################

function check()
{
              # http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html

        OLDIFS=$IFS
        IFS=$'\n'

        # Read all pom files into an array
        # - Search for user code modules: It searches for the tag <module> into the pom files and in case they contain modules,
        #checks if the autogenerated section has been modified. Reading text secuence from foo.txt file
        #
        # - Exclude model folder as the codegen poms therein require such a repository



        fileArray=($(find . -type f -not -path "./folder1/*" -not -path "*/folder2/*" -not -path "./folder3/*" -name "pom.xml" \
                         | xargs `awk -v RS='^$' 'NR==FNR{str=$0;next} /<module>/ && !index($0,str){print FILENAME}' sequence {} +`))


        IFS=$OLDIFS

        # get length of an array
        numberOfFiles=${#fileArray[@]}

        # read all filenames
        for (( i=0; i<${numberOfFiles}; i++ ));
        do
          echo "ERROR:Found user code modules (file:line:occurrence): ${fileArray[$i]}"
        done


    if [ "$numberOfFiles" != "0" ]; then
        echo "SUMMARY:Found $numberOfFiles pom.xml file(s) containing user code modules."
        exit 1
    fi
}

check
```

----UPDATE (last console output)

```
    :~/temp> bash script.sh
awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `{}' for reading (No such file or directory)
ERROR:Found user code modules (file:line:occurrence): ./test_folder/test4/pom.xml ./tes                                                                        t_folder/test1/pom.xml ./test_folder/test2/pom.xml ./test_folder/test3/pom.xml
SUMMARY:Found 1 pom.xml file(s) containing user code modules.
```

Comment: I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: some tip how to use it for that particular case please?

Comment: Start with scripting for one file (no awk/find).

Comment: All pom files are in the same directory / subdirectories. I need to check into all of them. Thanks

Comment: That's not a safe way to capture a list of filenames into an array, btw. Look at what happens if a file is in a directory with whitespace in its name.

Comment: Also, `xargs` is only safe in handling arbitrary filenames if the `-0` or `-d` arguments are in use. Look at what happens with files with literal quotes in their names otherwise.

Comment: The filenames Array is working fine. I test some simple searchs. However, still not sure how can I detect all that text secuence, only into those Xml files containing <module> tag inside

Comment: The filenames array is only "working fine" because you're using simple enough filenames that they don't exercise the bugs. Why would you want to have code that you know has bugs in it, just because you aren't hitting those bugs *right now*?

Comment: ...if you don't believe me that they exist, `mkdir -p 'hello word' 'hello"cruel"world' && touch 'hello world/pom.xml' 'hello"cruel"world/pom.xml'`, then run your preexisting code, and run `declare -p fileArray` to dump the array's contents in unambiguous form.

Comment: Thanks for the input Charles. Im using a naming convention, just simple names, no spaces or characters

Comment: The worst data loss event I personally witnessed was caused by backup maintenance code that assumed that (critical billing) logs would follow a specific naming convention. A buffer overflow dumped garbage into a filename, the garbage included a `*` surrounded by whitespace, and the script deleted every single logfile in the directory. If you only write code to handle cases you *think* can happen, you're writing bugs in the places you think are impossible.

Comment: ...and if you're careless in the situations where you don't think a script's correctness is important, do you really think you'll be able to suddenly follow good habits and practices in the one day out of a year you're doing something that *really is* important, without making habits of paying attention to robust practices the rest of the time?

Comment: Thanks Charles. For that case the naming convention is very strict. I would suggest focus our efforts in the current solution from now on.

Comment: It was exceedingly strict in the aforementioned data-loss case as well -- `[0-9a-f]{24}` is pretty nearly as strict as they come. BTW, the fact that you're searching for a comment rather than semantic data is critical -- it'll help isolate you from the "just use XMLStarlet / xmllint" answers -- so I've amended it to the title.

Comment: I really appreciate your help and take in consideration. I will also appreciate new tips how to solve that case and testable scripts. Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding cyberciti.biz as a source of bash advice. The practices you're following will fail badly with filenames containing literal newlines (which, yes, are perfectly legal).

Comment: ...and the backticks you added to Ed's code are simply wrong.

Comment: ...so, let me explain the "simply wrong". When you put backticks around something, you're using command substitution -- meaning you're running a command, and replacing it *with its output*. Importantly, if you run ```xargs `foo` ```, then, `xargs` isn't running `foo` -- instead, it's running a command formed by string-splitting and glob-expanding *the output of* `foo`.

Comment: ...and, if your command has no output at all, then `xargs` is run with no arguments, so it goes back to its default behavior of printing all the filenames it's given on input (the default command for `xargs` is `echo`).

Comment: Thanks, actually it does output the name of all files scanned and the one with the sequence. However there is 2 files with this sequence not only one in my test folder. Some tip?

Comment: You're doubling down on a mistake. Stop, go back, read what we said *carefully*. Just because it's printing filenames doesn't mean it's running `awk`.

Answer (score 1):

Store that text in a file named foo and then run:

```
find ... -exec awk -v RS='^$' 'NR==FNR{str=$0;next} /<module>/ && !index($0,str){print FILENAME}' foo {} +
```

Use whatever find options work for you to get the list of XML files. Whether you use -exec or pipe to xargs is up to you, I'm really just addressing the awk part as that seems to be what you're having trouble with.

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS and does a strict search for the entire contents of `foo` appearing exactly as written as a string in each of the XML files and prints the name of any file that does contain `<module>` but does not contain that string.

If that doesn't do what you want then edit your question to show a more complete sample input/output example including the text you want to search for **in context** in the input file.

Comment: Can this only handle one XML file per invocation, or could we make it `-exec ... {} +` to minimize the number of `awk` invocations?

Comment: Good point. I'll update it to use `{} +` as the awk script doesn't care how many XML files it gets called with as arguments. I was sidestepping the `find` details :-).

Comment: Thanks so much for teach me that advance and detailed answer. Im gonna check tomorrow at 10am (UTC/GMT) and let you know. However looks very promising :)

Comment: awk: fatal: cannot open file `foo' for reading (No such file or directory) - :(( working on it...

Comment: Please see full script in the UPDATE in the 1st input...help please

Comment: Found the issue - need accent (`) before awk and at the end of the expression. However i suspect doesnt work properly yet... only detecting one Pom for all cases and print the name of all the poms.... Code in the update

Comment: No, that is not the issue. You're mixing up `-exec awk '...' foo {} +` syntax and `| xargs awk '...' foo` syntax. Idk what a "Pom" is. You have to create the file named `foo`, see the first sentence of my answer. Try the awk script on a couple of files without the find first to make sure it works for you and THEN add in the find.

Comment: I have updated the code and test it. It runs, but only detect one file even if reads more containing the sequence in foo file. Somebody can help me and run it too? i guess we miss a loop somewhere... Thanks!! :)

Comment: Btw, this is my output when i execute the script - 1 error even it runs:                  awk: cmd. line:1: fatal: cannot open file `{}' for reading (No such file or directory)
ERROR:Found user code modules (file:line:occurrence): ./test_folder/test4/pom.xml ./tes                                                                     t_folder/test1/pom.xml ./test_folder/test2/pom.xml ./test_folder/test3/pom.xml
SUMMARY:Found 1 pom.xml file(s) containing user code modules.

Comment: No, we are NOT missing a loop anywhere (see [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)). If you can't edit your question to show THE command you are executing and THE files you are executing on then there's really nothing more we can do to help you debug the code you aren't showing us.

Comment: I added it to the 1st message also. Thanks! Maybe now is more clear the issue

Comment: As you can see is finding 1 file with this pattern, however i used it in 2 files.

Comment: So you STILL have backticks around the awk command and are STILL mixing up -exec/xargs syntax after @CharlesDuffy and I told you not to do that, explained why, and told you what to do instead. Guess why your command is failing? Hint - see my comment from yesterday starting with `No, that is not the issue` and Charles comments starting from `...and the backticks you added to Ed's code are simply wrong.`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will try to figure out what is wrong...hope to find it out :)

Comment: Im actually looking at it but still I think i missed somthing...  I rolled back but is not able to run it as desired. Could you give me some more light? In case is running for you, the final version of the command or script will be perfect so I can start to test. Thanks a lot

Comment: You didn't provide any sample input/output in your question so we can't test it, only you can do that. Did you actually try what I suggested yesterday: `Try the awk script on a couple of files without the find first to make sure it works for you and THEN add in the find`? Did it work? If not, in what way did it fail? Edit your question to show what you ran, the input files you ran it against, the output you got, and the output you expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xmllint` to search for a node using xpath

```
xmllint --xpath '//module' */pom.xml
```

Its return codes can tell you when it was found (`0`) or not (`!= 0`).

Comment: Thanks Diego, how can I detect that sequence with Xmllint ?