# Skip directories in a search in Python

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
import re
import os
from os.path import join
comment=re.compile(r"<!--\s+\| Start of user code \(user defined modules\)\s+\|-->\s+<!--\s+\| End of user code\s+\|-->", re.MULTILINE)
tag="<module>"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/temp/"):
 dirs.remove("/home/temp/test1")
 dirs.remove("/home/temp/test2")
 dirs.remove("/home/temp/test3")

       if "pom.xml" in files:
        p=join(root, "pom.xml") 
        print("Checking",p)
        with open(p) as f:
            s=f.read()
        if tag in s and comment.search(s):
            print("The following file contains user code modules:-------------> ",p)
```

But I get an error that says:

```
python /home/temp/test_folder/python_script_4.py
  File "/home/temp/test_folder/python_script_4.py", line 12
    if "pom.xml" in files:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

What is wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Additonally i get this error lately even if the folder exist:    IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: This error is unrelated to your question. Are you sure indentations are correct in the file?

Comment: The error is not related to your question, the error is only related to your indentation

Comment: I updated with input/output. Some help?thanks

Comment: Unindent the `if "pom.xml"` line to match with `dirs.remove("/home/temp/test3")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your indentation of the if doesn't match the current indentation

```
import re
import os
from os.path import join
comment=re.compile(r"<!--\s+\| Start of user code \(user defined modules\)\s+\|-->\s+<!--\s+\| End of user code\s+\|-->", re.MULTILINE)
tag="<module>"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/dlopez/temp/"):
 dirs.remove("/home/dlopez/temp/test1")
 dirs.remove("/home/dlopez/temp/test2")
 dirs.remove("/home/dlopez/temp/test3")

       if "pom.xml" in files:  # The if statement is not aligned to anything
        p=join(root, "pom.xml") 
        print("Checking",p)
        with open(p) as f:
            s=f.read()
        if tag in s and comment.search(s):
            print("The following file contains user code modules:-------------> ",p)
```

Change it to:

```
import re
import os
from os.path import join
comment=re.compile(r"<!--\s+\| Start of user code \(user defined modules\)\s+\|-->\s+<!--\s+\| End of user code\s+\|-->", re.MULTILINE)
tag="<module>"

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("/home/dlopez/temp/"):
    # Skip the dirs you want looping a list
    for skipped in ("/home/dlopez/temp/test1", "/home/dlopez/temp/test1", "/home/dlopez/temp/test3"):
        if skipped in dirs: dirs.remove(skipped)

    if "pom.xml" in files:
        p=join(root, "pom.xml") 
        print("Checking",p)
        with open(p) as f:
           s=f.read()
           if tag in s and comment.search(s):
              print("The following file contains user code modules:-------------> ",p)
```

Comment: In addition, do not mix tabs and spaces in your code. Use either tabs, or spaces - spaces are preferred [as per PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id17).

Comment: Additionally, 4 spaces are recommended by PEP8, which makes code way mroe legible.

Comment: Well, the message is clear, it can't remove x because x is not in the list

Comment: You're welcome, please vote/accept answer as it solved your question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers